# Apply output format only to specific commands using [format] config section

Tags: git

I modified `gitconfig` to obtain a colorful and easier to read `git log`:

```
[format]
    pretty = %C(yellow)%h %C(green)(%cd) %C(reset)%s%C(bold yellow)%d %C(bold cyan)<%an>%C(reset)
```

The issue is that this formatting also applies to `git show`, so I don't have any easy way to read multiple-lines commit messages anymore.

So far, I came up with two annoying solutions:

- leaving `gitconfig` with this format section and use `--pretty=medium` when I want to see multi-lines commit messages.
- removing the format section from `gitconfig` and create aliases for oneline logs:

  l = log --decorate --pretty=format:'the whole formatting chain'
  ll = log --decorate -p --pretty=format:'the whole formatting chain again'

Is there any shorter or more elegant way to apply this kind of formatting to the `log` command only ?

Comment: I don't think there's anything more elegant.  I think the git folks should add `format.log`, `format.show`, etc., with `format` being a fallback default and with the ability to use indirect names, e.g., %[format.blah] would suck in format.blah directives.  (Syntax not meant as actual proposal, just general idea.)  Also, log should check for format.log.oneline etc depending on log options.  There is an ugly way to do "shorter" though, I'll put that in an answer...

Comment: Damn.  All those things I've been looking for and couldn't find (custom format classes, custom format per command)...  SO was my last resort.  Damn it damn it damn it.

Comment: Yes, I went looking for custom-format-per-command a while ago.  If it's actually in there I'd love to find out. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is distinctly non-pretty and non-elegant, but at least you can tweak the format in one place:

```
[alias]
    l = !git log "--pretty=format:\"$(git config --get myformats.log)\"" --decorate
```

(add `ll` etc., as desired).  The quoting above was found by experiment....

```
[myformats]
    log = %C(yellow)%h %C(green)(%cd) %C(reset)%s%C(bold yellow)%d %C(bold cyan)<%an>%C(reset)
```